# How to push elements in a stack using C

Tags: c, stack

I tried to learn a stack in C. But unable to do the push operation as it shows some errors in it. There is no error message shown in the console. But when running the code, it shows a wrong top value when executing the peek method.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define MAX 50
typedef enum{FALSE,TRUE} boolean;
typedef struct stack{
    int top;
    int a[MAX];
 }stack;
void CreateStack(stack s){
    s.top = -1;
 }
 boolean isEmpty(stack s){
    return (s.top == -1);
}
boolean isFull(stack s){
    return(s.top == MAX - 1);
}
void push(stack s, int data){
    if(isFull(s)){
        printf("Stack is Full\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else{
        s.top = s.top + 1;
        s.a[s.top] = data;
    }
 }
 void pop(stack s){
    if(isEmpty(s)){
        printf("Stack is Empty");
        exit(1);
    }
    else{
        printf("%d\n",s.a[s.top]);
        s.top = s.top - 1;
    }
 }
 int peek(stack s){
    return s.a[s.top];
 }
 void main(){
    stack s;
    CreateStack(s);
    int num;
    push(s,1);
    push(s,2);
    push(s,15);
    printf("Top value = %d\n",peek(s));
 }
```

Comment: If you want help debugging your code, it *may* be handy to let us see your code :-)

Comment: "as it shows some errors in it." Show. The code. The error. Your thinking. Make a [mre]. Provide sample data which provokes the problem. Explain in detail the way in which the mentioned errors manifest. Show everything directly here, as text not picture. Quote verbatim errors and output.

Comment: Take the [tour]. Read [ask]. Please.

Comment: I have to admit, that at first I was tempted to comment differently. After I resisted the temptation and instead provided some guiding comments, allow me to vent my feelings by jokingly writing the following. It will make some of the people here smile and thereby put them in a more helpful mood. That will be to your benefit, once you [edit]ed your question to provide the needed info. "Your problem is caused by the second part of the data. In line ten of your code. You know, where you are doing that thing to the other thing. That cannot work like that. Do it the other way - you know."

Comment: Sorry it was posted before adding the code. Now i corrected it and added the code here

Comment: A well. I was wrong, it is not line 10, it is line 9 (I probably expected an empty line for readability somewhere). Where you do the parameter handover to that function as call by value. Do it the other way, call by reference. And the same in all other functions.

Comment: For people trying to get the joke here: My feeling-venting comment was BEFORE the code was visible and it was completely correct, just for an off-by-one in the line number I predicted. Sorry, but I find that funny. (Ah, OK, the part about the second part of the data was not to the point...)

Comment: Call-by-reference is done in C with pointers, that is important to know of course.

Comment: @Yunnosch More accurately, call-by-reference is *mimiced* with pointers in C. (And it's pass-by-reference, not call-by-reference)

Comment: @klutt Many, many thanks. (no sarcasm intended) Because I was always uncomfortable with "call". I also accept your better phrasing of "mimiced" (though I wonder about using another "k"...).

Comment: @Yunnosch Learn Swedish, and then you can use a "k" in mimic. :D But I have to confess that I am a bit confused. "Pass by" feels much better, but "call by" has a lot more hits on google for both reference and value. So I'm not sure here. But both seem accepted, so I'm going to stick with "pass by"

Comment: @klutt I feel like switching to "pass" experimentally and seeing how many complaints (or edits on my posts) I harvest.

Comment: @klutt I will go with another "k" after all. https://www.dictionary.com/browse/mimicked

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are not modifying the struct you are passing as argument. Each function has a local copy which ceases to exist at the end of the function. Here is a sample of the `push` and `main` function. Make the same changes to all functions.

```
void push(stack *s, int data){
    if(isFull(s)){
        printf("Stack is Full\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else{
        s->top = s->top + 1;
        s->a[s->top] = data;
    }
 }

void main(){
    stack s;
    CreateStack(&s);
    push(&s,1);
    push(&s,2);
    push(&s,15);
    printf("Top value = %d\n",peek(&s));
}
```

You could avoid pointers for `isEmpty`, `isFull` and `peek` since they are not modifying anything. But I thought it was easiest to have the same interface for all of them. For safety, you can declare them like `bool isFull(stack const *s)`