# How to convert a decimal to binary in C programming using stack

Tags: c

I'm trying a C programming code which will convert a decimal number into binary number and the binary values will be stored in a stack

According to my code, when running it shows some error responses. When trying to display the binary number using peek method, the application runs without an end.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define MAX 50
typedef enum{FALSE, TRUE} boolean;
typedef struct stack{
    int top;
    int a[MAX];
} stack;
void CreateStack(stack *s){
    s->top = -1;
}
boolean isEmpty(stack *s){
    return (s->top == -1);
}
boolean isFull(stack *s){
    return(s->top == MAX - 1);
}
void push(stack *s, int data){
    if(isFull(s)){
        exit(1);
    }
    else{
        s->top = s->top + 1;
        s->a[s->top] = data;
    }
}
int pop(stack *s){
    if(isEmpty(s)){
        exit(1);
    }
    else{
        return s->a[s->top];
        s->top = s->top - 1;
    }
}
int peek(stack *s){
    return s->a[s->top];
}
void binary(stack *s, int num){
    int n;
    while(num != 0){
        if(!isFull(s)){
             n = num % 2;
            push(s,n);
            num = num / 2;
        }
        else{
            exit(1);
        }
    }
}
void main() {
    stack s;
    CreateStack(&s);
    int num,n;
    printf("Enter the decimal number: ");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    binary(&s,num);
    printf("Top = %d\n",peek(&s));
    while(!isEmpty(&s)){
        printf("%d ",pop(&s));
    }
}
```

Comment: Aside: the decimal to binary conversion happens with `scanf("%d",&num);`

Comment: Time to learn how to use a *debugger* to debug your code. Use a debugger to step through the code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values. That way you should (hopefully) easily see the problem when it happens and should (again hopefully) be able to figure out how to solve it.

Comment: Another aside: you haven't used the values in `typedef enum{FALSE, TRUE} boolean;` but if you `#include <stdbool.h>` that will give you the type `bool` and the values `false` and `true`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to push elements in a stack using C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58602214/how-to-push-elements-in-a-stack-using-c)

Comment: Also note that it is `int main(void)`, not `void main()`. C is not Java. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pop()` contains dead code — it returns value but `top` decrement placed after the return operator and will be newer reached.

```
int pop(stack *s){
    if(isEmpty(s)){
        exit(1);
    }
    else{
        return s->a[s->top];
        s->top = s->top - 1; // <------------
    }
 }
```

Change it in following manner:

```
int pop(stack *s){
    if(isEmpty(s)){
        exit(1);
    }
    else{
        int temp = s->a[s->top];
        s->top = s->top - 1;
        return temp;
    }
 }
```

p.s. As for me, `else` keyword can be omitted here but it is taste issue:

```
int pop(stack *s) {
    int temp;

    if(isEmpty(s))
        exit(1);

    temp = s->a[s->top];
    s->top = s->top - 1;
    return temp;
 }
```

Comment: Some coders dislike it, but it's perfectly ok to just do `return s->[s->top--]`

Comment: @klutt Yes, the same is beter for me — `return s->[s->top--];` and `s->a[++s->top] = data;`. But it is beyond of the topic and could be too complex for beginner.